Connecting to SQL Server (Docker) from Microsoft Fabric not working
for a copy activity in a Data Factory pipeline (within MS Fabric) I am trying to set SQL Server (Docker) as a destination.
However, I am getting the below error:

An exception occurred: DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My connection settings:
 Server - localhost:1433 
 Database - stock_market 
 Username - sa
 Password - yourStrong(!)Password

Docker command used to download and run image:
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password" --name sqlserver -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

Please help. Thanks!
Edit: Please see image of error below


No problem here (I changed 1433:1433 to 1440:14433 because of another server on 1433, but D:\TEMP>sqlcmd -S nas3,1440 -U sa -P yourStrong(!)Password worked, showing Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU27) (KB5037331) - 15.0.4375.4 (X64) as (the start of the response from SELECT @@VERSION

even under Windows it worked (with some patience before server started): https://i.sstatic.net/wiSMBTQY.png

thanks Luuk. my issue is not from the command prompt. I am trying to connect to SQL Server as a data destination from Microsoft Fabric.

@Luuk, please see image of error in the edited post above.

Sorry, I do not know why Microsoft makes it so hard to connect to a SQL server instance...

Where exactly is your Docker container running? How is the Fabric process running in the cloud going to know that localhost means your Docker container instead of itself?

Isn't fabric some cloud thing? How can it find your localhost

I resolved it by installing a data gateway from Fabric. I followed the steps from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIu2bJxzsd8
